# How to calculate prognostic score for propensity score matching?

Tags: propensity-scores, matching

I wish to compute prognostic score for propensity score matching.

1. Must I train the regression model (on the control set) for unmatched or for matched data?
2. If the outcome is binary, must I assess the difference in the means of fitted values or in the proportions of predicted 1-s (assume outcome 1 when the fitted value >0.5 and outcome 0 when the fitted value < 0.5)?

I did read:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cobalt/vignettes/cobalt.html#using-the-prognostic-score-for-balance-assessment

Elizabeth A. Stuart, Brian K. Lee, Finbarr P. Leacy,
Prognostic score–based balance measures can be a useful diagnostic for propensity score methods in comparative effectiveness research, Journal of Clinical Epidemiology, Volume 66, Issue 8, Supplement, 2013, Pages S84-S90.e1, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jclinepi.2013.01.013

Zhang Z, Kim HJ, Lonjon G, Zhu Y; written on behalf of AME Big-Data Clinical Trial Collaborative Group. Balance diagnostics after propensity score matching. Ann Transl Med. 2019 Jan;7(1):16. doi: 10.21037/atm.2018.12.10. PMID: 30788363; PMCID: PMC6351359

Ben B. Hansen, The prognostic analogue of the propensity score, Biometrika, Volume 95, Issue 2, June 2008, Pages 481–488, https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/asn004

But did not manage to find answers to the questions.